# Insert if not exist and update if exist, without primary key

Tags: sql, upsert

I need to insert row if not exist, and update if exist, but not with primary key.

For example - this is my table structure:

```
id -> int(11), primary key, auto increment.
code -> char(20).
name -> char(50).
```

My table:

| id | code | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | code1 | name1 |
| 2 | code2 | name2 |

I tried this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (code, name)  
VALUES ('code2edited', 'name2edited') 
    ON EXISTS (SELECT code, name FROM myTable WHERE code = 'code2') 
UPDATE code = 'code2edited', name = 'name2edited'
```

This SQL will throw an error, but my expected result is:

| id | code | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | code1 | name1 |
| 2 | code2edited | name2edited |

And if not exist is:

| id | code | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | code1 | name1 |
| 2 | code2 | name2 |
| 3 | code2edited | name2edited |

Comment: I don't see this working without a key. How do you know which entry should be updated? If you know the previous value as suggested in your given statement, you already know that that entry exists, so you can just update?

Comment: @tobiv         i dont know how to explain but i need to "if field code=code2 then update that row to be row('code2edited','name2edited'), else insert row('','code2edited','name2edited')"

Comment: Is this in a trigger so you have access to what the row was previously? Or can you pass in what the old value was? Otherwise, how could SQL tell what the old value of Code was so it could know if it should update or add? Is this being called from code that knows the old value (i.e. a C# program) so you might pass in an extra parameter informing SQL of the old value?

Comment: What dbms (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc) do you use? What version?

Comment: The only robust way to do this without using a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY constraint to catch duplicates is to use your host language, or maybe a stored function. Start a SQL transaction, do a SELECT to determine whether your row already exists. Then either UPDATE it or INSERT the new one, then commit the transaction.

Comment: It simply doesn't make sense if both of the fields are changed. Either one of the fields stays the same and you use a unique key, or you know the previous value and thus you already know it exists, so you simply update? This would be program logic, not SQL. Maybe it would help to know what exactly you're using this for. Is it a coding excercise?